# Can we figured out the total money supply using MB?

Tags: money-supply, federal-reserve

If we look at the total in the federal reserves account 
[Here](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/RESBALNSW) at the moment is about 3 trillion and if the reserve requirement is 10% does that mean that there is at least 30 trillion out there in money supply?

I know that there can be excess reserves, but give the fact that the reserves have increased dramatically in shot period of time, we can assume that there was a shortage and not excess of supply meaning the 3T were needed to back up around 30T.

Comment: Why do you think they measure M2 etc. if MB was enough? Or are you asking about a deriving just some bounds from M2 from MB (since you say "at least")? You need clarify (at least) what you mean by "total money supply".

Comment: For a (simplified) explanation on the relationship between these see https://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/watkins/moneymultiplier.htm (and https://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/watkins/money.htm)

Comment: @Fizz I was thinking beyond m2, including m3 and m4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are [the money supply statistics from the Federal Reserve.](https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/h6/current/default.htm)

You cannot infer wider money numbers from the monetary base, since there are excess reserves. Those excess reserves were not created to “back up” deposits, it was a deliberate action to expand the monetary base.